# Can we use dynamic parameters in codepipe liine?

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I want to use dynamic parameters while configuring a codepipeline. Like using a ssn parameter store variable while configuring a stage. Is it possible ?

Example: I have a cloud formation stage in a codepipeline and I want to change the stack name which I am creating each time before running the pipeline with out actually editing the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still an open question... but just in case... Sad to say that, 9 months later, at least in my experience, there's no way (yet) to dynamically change your pipe's setup out of the box, even more, if  you try to do something like that, automatically, while the pipe is running... the whole execution will be stopped.